# Delaying initialization of object in Python until all information is available

Tags: python

I have a situation in my project where in order to initialize an object I need, say, 3 parameters. But, during construction I have only 2 of the parameters available. Then, at a later point the third parameter is available.
At this point I wish to initialize the object.

Here is how I solved it:

```
class Base(object):
    #abstract
    def initialize(self, extraArgs):        
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        def closure(self, extraArgs): 
            self._initialize(extraArgs, arg1, arg2)
        self.initialize = types.MethodType(closure, self)

    def _initialize(self, extraArgs, arg1, arg2):
        # do something with all of extraArgs, arg1, arg2


d = Derived(x, y) #only x and y are available at this point

#in a later context working with Base class, the missing z is available
d.initialize(z)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? How could I avoid the triple duplication of "extraArgs, arg1, arg2"?

Comment: Why don't you just directly define a method `initialize(self, z)` that does what you want, and then call it?  I don't see what you hope to gain by using a dynamically-defined method just to call another method, and passing arguments you already passed in before.

Comment: Why can't you initialize the object after you have all the necessary arguments?

Comment: If there's a necessary case to initialize the instance first, then why don't you modify it later on?

Comment: @BrenBarn It's not crucial but I don't want to have boilerplate code that saves temporary arg1\arg2\others aside each time a derived class is implemented. I rather that everything is uniformly available in a single function without polluting the class with temps. It would be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial from functools. You can pass the class name and 2 of the arguments, then pass the third whenever you are right and get back the object you need.

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c

from functools import partial
pa = partial(P, 1, 2)
pa # This is a partial, not the oject you need
<functools.partial at 0x7feeb00e7e68>
pa(3) # This is the object you need
<__main__.P at 0x7feeb00d8bd0>
```

Comment: You can just use variadic function with variable arguments `*args`.

Comment: Is there a way to hide this complexity from the user code? that is, keep a clean interface like d = Derived(1, 2)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think what you wanted to achieve do not need inheritance. You can use meta programming in Python, knowing **Class** is also an object.

Here a modification to a Class's property gets "reflected" to its already initialized object(s). So you need not worry about when you initialize it.

```
class SomeClass():
    """
    use variable arguments so it's ok to initialize
    with any number of arguments
    """
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for index, arg in enumerate(args):
            # do something with the arguments                                                                                     
            if index == 0:
                self.arg1 = arg
            elif index == 1:
                self.arg2 = arg
            elif index == 2:
                self.arg3 = arg

class Revealer():
    """
    Inject random cute words to SomeClass's third argument
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.misty = ["baz","maple", "syrup", "baby", "cereal"]
        self.gen = self.misty_generator()

    def misty_generator(self):
        for i in self.misty:
            yield i

    def inject_misty(self, class_):
        class_.arg3 = self.gen.next()

# Meta-programming                                                                                                                
SomeClass.arg1 = "cake"
SomeClass.arg2 = "merinque"                                                                             
SomeClass.arg3 = lambda self: None

d = SomeClass("foo", "bar")
print(d.arg1, d.arg2, d.arg3())  # print "foo", "bar", None

r = Revealer()

r.inject_misty(SomeClass) 
print(d.arg1, d.arg2, d.arg3)    # print "foo", "bar", "baz"

r.inject_misty(SomeClass)
print(d.arg1, d.arg2, d.arg3)    # print "foo", "bar", "maple"

r.inject_misty(SomeClass)
print(d.arg1, d.arg2, d.arg3)    # print "foo", "bar", "syrup"
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly it. SomeClass.arg3 is shared across instances, but what if I want a different arg3 per instance?

Comment: @Leo then you add instance property to each instance.